# How to you insert into MySQL database and returns its id in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Is there a way to insert into MySQL database using PHP PDO and return its id? Or I will just have to search fot its id after insertion?

Answer (score 5):

```
$pdo_object->lastInsertId();
```

See [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: what happen if there is concurrent insertion?

Comment: @Phen: That's another question entirely. @Chacha102 provided an excellent answer to *this* question already.

Comment: You might want to check out this comment about thread-safeness: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#84530 (Just a quick Ctrl+F search on the Docuementation for the word 'safe')

Comment: +1 for being quicker on the draw, but shouldn't the d be lowercased? ;)

Comment: @much Well, All PHP functions are case-insensitive .. so.... doesn't really matter too much.

Comment: @Chacha: very interesting. I guess I assumed that b/c variable names were case sensitive, functions were as well. Prob better practice to code in a case sensitive manner anyway, though

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for [`PDO::lastInsertID`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)?

Comment: So .. it took me just a *little* less time to search the documentation? :P

Comment: I +1'd you for being first ;)

Comment: @much See my comment on my answer.